# Auto draft with background changes

Tags: tasks, content, draft

I have an entry with a readonly json field (Jason plugin). This field is populate with data from an external api. So I have a button in my entry page that call a custom route which call the api and save the data in the entry. This part works fine.

My problem is when I click on my button, a draft is created before action is done. Since I'm not using the save button from craft, the draft is not deleted and when I go back to the entry I have this notice:

> Recent changes to the Current revision have been merged into this draft.

But the json data is not updated. If I cancel the changes (Showing your unsaved changes), the entry is fine.

Is there a way to avoid the creation of the draft when I click the button, or if I can delete the current in my custom code before saving the data?

Here's a snippet of the save:

```
$restaurant = Entry::find()
                ->section('restaurants')
                ->slug('restaurant-1')
                ->one();
$restaurant->setFieldValue('restaurant_schedules', Json::encode($schedules));
Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($restaurant);
```

Edit 1 :

The button is a simple route with the entry slug in the url that called this controller. (/sync/schedule/my-entry-slug) This controller create a new job in the queue that will update the entry.

```
public function actionSync($restaurantSlug)
{
    $restaurantService = new RestaurantsService();
    $restaurant = $restaurantService->getRestaurantBySlug($restaurantSlug);

    Queue::push(new ScheduleSingleJob([
                    'restaurant' => $restaurant,
                    ]),
                self::JOBS_PRIORITY
    );

    return $this->redirect('/admin/entries/restaurants');
}
```

Here's some screenshots of my steps.

1. I click on the button in the sidebar
2. Before the page is redirect to the link, a draft is created for my entry.

[image: screenshot1]

and when I come back after the queue is done, the draft is shown without the changes applied to the entry. (I need to click cancel draft to see them)

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Hi. it seems the job is about one restaurant. so what if update and save the restaurant element in sync action and redirect to edit page like :  return $this->redirect($restaurant->getCpEditUrl());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this can work?:

```
if ($restraunt->isDraft) {
  return; // Skip draft
}
```

Or if not and you really want to purge ALL drafts, you can do this:

```
use craft\services\Drafts;
...

((new Drafts())->purgeUnsavedDrafts());
```

Just to clarify, does your button fire custom controller? Or are you saving data from the API in the event hook?

**UPD**:

Can you try this after you have saved your entry?

I just stole this piece of code from the entry controller

```
$provisional = Entry::find()
            ->provisionalDrafts()
            ->draftOf($restraunt->id)
            ->siteId($restraunt->siteId)
            ->anyStatus()
            ->one();
if ($provisional) {
            Craft::$app->getElements()->deleteElement($provisional, true);
 }
```

Comment: I 've edited my post with more informations. The button fire a custom controller that will create a job in a queue to update the entry.

Comment: The purgeUnsavedDrafts doesn't seem to work, I need to test furthermore if I can manage something while changing the purgeUnsavedDraftsDuration config.

Answer (score 1):

I found a temporary workaround by deleting draft from my entry Id with a simple query.

```
use craft\db\Query;
use craft\db\Table;
    
(new Query)
     ->createCommand()
     ->delete(Table::DRAFTS, ['canonicalId' => $entry->id])
     ->execute();
```

Comment: Can you try my updated answer?

Comment: The updated answer works after the entry save.